# How to convert this SQL select to LINQ query?

Tags: sql, linq

I want to convert this SQL to LINQ, but encounter difficulties, can anybody help me? thanks a lot, here is the SQL codes:

```
select publication_id, publication_code, publication_name 
from tbl_PUBLICATION 
where AIG_PUB = 1 
order by PUBLICATION_NAME
```

by the way, the AIG_PUB field is bit type,

Comment: And by difficulties you mean what? What did you encounter, what did you research and attempt to overcome that obstacle?

Comment: Perhaps my [LINQ to SQL Recipe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49245160/sql-to-linq-with-multiple-join-count-and-left-join/49245786#49245786) may prove helpful. Obviously `AIG_PUB` is not boolean in SQL or it wouldn't be comparable to `1` and most SQL servers don't support boolean, so the question is what is it's actual type in SQL? Also, are what database engine/provider are you using? Are you using EF?

Comment: i suggest you download linqpad : http://www.linqpad.net/download.aspx and have try its easy

Comment: or you can have look to this http://www.sqltolinq.com/

Comment: given my answer have look and try out ...i am not giving you actual answer but you can learn from answer and create query for you

Comment: have you have to build query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
tbl_PUBLICATION
.Where(p => p.AIG_PUB)
.OrderBy(p => p.PUBLICATION_NAME);
```

or if you insist to select only those columns

```
tbl_PUBLICATION
.Where(p => p.AIG_PUB == true)
.OrderBy(p => p.PUBLICATION_NAME)
.Select(p => new {
    publication_id = p.publication_id,
    publication_code = p.publication_code,
    publication_name = p.publication_name
});
```

Comment: thank you so much for your help, H.Danesh, I will try your codes next Monday and let you know then, have a great weekend!

Answer (score 1):

Apart from below suggest you make use of [LinqPad tool - free](http://www.linqpad.net/download.aspx), it has sample that can also help you

---

I am not giving you actual answer but you can learn from answer and create query for you

its simple ,  you have have look to this image

**Sql query**

```
Select firstname,LastName from [User] where id = 3
```

**Converted linq query**

[image]

You can check this : [SQL to LINQ ( Visual Representation )](http://pranayamr.blogspot.com/2010/12/sql-to-linq-visual-representation.html)

Comment: the AIG_PUB is bit type

Comment: @user2949042 - then you should use `boolean` type in c# which is equivalent to bit type of database

Answer (score 0):

This should probably do it.

```
var MyResults = tbl1_PUBLICATION
.Where( x => x.AIG_PUB == 1)
.Select( p => new {
 publication_id = p.publication_id,
 publication_code = p.publication_code,
 publication_name = p.publication_name})
.OrderBy( p => p.PublicationName);
```

I haven't tested it, so if you see any typos, please let me know,

Comment: thank you so much for your help, I will try your codes next Monday and let you know then, have a great weekend!